# ANN problem: I am building an ANN model to predict the profit of a new startup based on certain features

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, mlp

[The image of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpVsG.png)

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
```

## Loading the data set using pandas as data frame format

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"E:\50_Startups.csv")
df.drop(['State'],axis = 1, inplace = True)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
mm = MinMaxScaler()
df.iloc[:,:] = mm.fit_transform(df.iloc[:,:])
info = df.describe()

x = df.iloc[:,:-1].values
y = df.iloc[:,-1].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split( x,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

## Initializing the model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(40,input_dim =3,activation="relu",kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Dense(30,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",optimizer="adam",metrics=["accuracy"])
```

## fitting model on train data

```
model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train,epochs=150, batch_size=32,verbose=1)
```

## Evaluating the model on test data

```
eval_score_test = model.evaluate(x_test,y_test,verbose = 1)
```

I am getting zero accuracy.

Comment: What does the "verbose" output say about the loss values over the epochs?

Comment: 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 219ms/step - loss: 0.1172 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to say Thank you to everyone who took their precious time to help me. I am posting this code as this worked for me. I hope it helps everyone who is stuck somewhere looking for answers. I got this code after consulting with my friend.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Loading the data set using pandas as data frame format 
startups = pd.read_csv(r"E:\0Assignments\DL_assign\50_Startups.csv")
startups = startups.drop("State", axis =1)

train, test = train_test_split(startups, test_size = 0.2)

x_train = train.iloc[:,0:3].values.astype("float32")
x_test = test.iloc[:,0:3].values.astype("float32")
y_train = train.Profit.values.astype("float32")
y_test = test.Profit.values.astype("float32")

def norm_func(i):
     x = ((i-i.min())/(i.max()-i.min()))
     return (x)

x_train = norm_func(x_train)
x_test = norm_func(x_test)
y_train = norm_func(y_train)
y_test = norm_func(y_test)

# one hot encoding outputs for both train and test data sets 
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)

# Storing the number of classes into the variable num_of_classes 
num_of_classes = y_test.shape[1]
x_train.shape
y_train.shape
x_test.shape
y_test.shape

# Creating a user defined function to return the model for which we are
# giving the input to train the ANN mode
def design_mlp():
    # Initializing the model 
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(500,input_dim =3,activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(200,activation="tanh"))
    model.add(Dense(100,activation="tanh"))
    model.add(Dense(50,activation="tanh"))
    model.add(Dense(num_of_classes,activation="linear"))
    model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",optimizer="adam",metrics = 
    ["accuracy"])
    return model

# building a cnn model using train data set and validating on test data set
model = design_mlp()

# fitting model on train data
model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train,batch_size=100,epochs=10)

# Evaluating the model on test data  
eval_score_test = model.evaluate(x_test,y_test,verbose = 1)
print ("Accuracy: %.3f%%" %(eval_score_test[1]*100)) 

# accuracy score on train data 
eval_score_train = model.evaluate(x_train,y_train,verbose=0)
print ("Accuracy: %.3f%%" %(eval_score_train[1]*100))
```

Comment: what you have done is incorrect in several aspects. First the problem is a `Regression` based problem and you have misinterpreted it as a `Classification` Problem. Second If any of the above mentioned answers were working then you should have mentioned that at least in the comments. Not replying to it in any form and then posting your answer 2 days later. I found it bit insulting for the trouble I went to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that accuracy is a metric for discrete values (classification).

you should use:

r2 score
mape
smape

instead.

e.g:

```
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",optimizer="adam",metrics=["mean_absolute_percentage_error"])
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and got -
    eval_score_test = model.evaluate(x_test,y_test,verbose = 1)
    1/1 [==============================] - 0s 215ms/step - loss: 0.0044  
     mean_absolute_percentage_error: 61.0093

Comment: all fine, now you have to work the data (more samples or more features) and the model itself to improve your result. Try to make some predictions in new single input data and see if the output makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of @GuintherKovalski accuracy is not for regression but if you still want to use it then you can use it along with some threshold using following steps:

1. Set a threshold such that if the absolute difference in the predicted value and the actual value is less than equal to the threshold then you consider that value as correct, otherwise false.
2. Ex -> `predicted values = [0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.2], original values = [0.2, 0.8, 0.5, 0.4]`.
   Now `abs diff -> [0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2]` and let's take a threshold of `0.2`. So with this threshold the `correct -> [1, 1, 0, 1]` and your accuracy will be `correct.sum()/len(correct)` and that is `3/4 -> 0.75`.

This could be implemented in TensorFlow like this

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

data = make_regression(10000)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(100,))])

def custom_metric(a, b):
    threshold = 1 # Choose accordingly
    abs_diff = tf.abs(b - a)
    correct = abs_diff >= threshold
    correct = tf.cast(correct, dtype=tf.float16)
    res = tf.math.reduce_mean(correct)
    return res

model.compile('adam', 'mae', metrics=[custom_metric])
model.fit(data[0], data[1], epochs=30, batch_size=32)
```